# How a subset of pretrained caffe model can be saved?

Tags: caffe, pre-trained-model

I am working on a pretrained caffe model (in python) which has 3 layers. I want to decompose this caffe model and create a new model the same as first layer of this model. For example:

Original Caffe model
data -> conv1_1 -> conv1_2 -> conv2_1 -> conv2_2 -> conv3_1 -> conv3_2

New Caffe model
data -> conv1_1 -> conv1_2

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python exposes the data inside the .caffemodel file. It can be accessed as an array. For example,

```
net = caffe.Net('path/to/conv.prototxt', 'path/to/conv.caffemodel', caffe.TEST)
W = net.params['con_1'][0].data[...]
b = net.params['con_1'][1].data[...]
```

You can copy this data into a new file and save it as a .caffemodel file. Have a look at [this](https://gist.github.com/FranciscoCanas/844aab52fcff6b1c652a) and [this](http://christopher5106.github.io/deep/learning/2015/09/04/Deep-learning-tutorial-on-Caffe-Technology.html).